# How to bind ZeroMQ socket with Ratchet web-socket library to make real time application for php application?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sockets, ratchet

I am just a beginner in this whole area involving websocket, Ratchet and ZeroMQ.

To my basic understanding:

`websocket` is something that helps to create open connection between server and client.

`Ratchet` is a PHP based library which uses PHP's core Socket functions to create a PHP socket framework allowing us to ease in PHP socket programming.

`ZeroMQ` is a socket library that helps non-ratchet application to (other PHP script) send the data over Ratchet Socket and web-socket.

I am following the tutorial found in ratchet about 'hello world' and 'pusher' but both of them seems to be incomplete and only teaches how to work with console only. I have also found ratchet-example in github but it is not properly documented. I was looking for a complete example (with a dedicated html page and javascript)

Below is the code I am working on: This is one of the method of the controller which I am making a Ajax request for. This method will create a new post (lets say). I want to update the list of post dynamically in multiple client's browser by broadcasting/pushing with the help of ZeroMq.

A method in a controller:

```
public function create_new_post(){
    // ------
    // code to create a new post.
    // -------

    // After creating a post
    $response = [
        'new_post_title'    => $title,
        'post_id'           => $id
    ];

    $context = new ZMQContext();
    $socket = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH, 'my pusher');
    $socket->connect("tcp://localhost:8000");
    $socket->send(json_encode($response));

}
```

Pusher File:

```
use Ratchet\ConnectionInterface;
use Ratchet\Wamp\WampServerInterface;

class Pusher implements WampServerInterface{

     public function onPostEntry($data){
         // Data that were sent by ZeroMQ through create_new_post() method
         $entry_data = json_decode($data);      

         // AND AFTER THIS, I DONT HAVE CLUE OF WHAT TO DO NEXT !!             

     }
}
```

Shell Script to run server:

```
require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$loop   = React\EventLoop\Factory::create();
$pusher = new MyApp\Pusher;

// Listen for the web server to make a ZeroMQ push after an ajax request
$context = new React\ZMQ\Context($loop);
$pull = $context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PULL);
$pull->bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:8000'); 
$pull->on('message', array($pusher, 'onBidEntry'));

// Set up our WebSocket server for clients wanting real-time updates
$webSock = new React\Socket\Server($loop);
$webSock->listen(8080, '0.0.0.0'); 
$webServer = new Ratchet\Server\IoServer(
    new Ratchet\Http\HttpServer(
        new Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer(
            new Ratchet\Wamp\WampServer(
                $pusher
            )
        )
    ),
    $webSock
);

$loop->run();
```

Shell script only tells that it will serve in port 8080, however how would I mention my routes. Lets say I want the open connection in only the page 'mysite/allposts'. Also, what would be the script that I have to write in client side (a javascript file) and how to receive these new data by client side updating a particular DOM object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I followed the examples you are talking about. They didn't seem incomplete to me, but I understand what you mean. Ratchet is a server side script and just allows you to write a service that implements websockets and that is able to listen to ZMQ messages. You will launch your Ratchet script on the command line and it runs as a service in parallel to Apache.

This is all independent from the client side of the websocket. Like they recommend, I used Autobahn.js on the client side. This library implements the WAMP protocol. It simplifies the client side code to the max.

The problem with your code is, that `class Pusher implements WampServerInterface` does not have a `public function onPostEntry`. This class has to implement the `WampServerInterface`, this means it must have at least these functions :

- onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic)
- onUnSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic)
- onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn)
- onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn)
- onPublish(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible
- onError(ConnectionInterface $conn, \Exception $e)
- onZMQMessage($jsondata)

There can be others for more advanced features, like `call`ing remote procedures on clients.

On the sender side (ZMQ message), put this code:

```
$zmq = new ZMQWrapper;
$zqm->publish('posts', $response);

class ZMQWrapper {
    function __construct(){
        $this->context = new ZMQContext();
        $this->socket = $this->context->getSocket(ZMQ::SOCKET_PUSH);
        $this->socket->setSockOpt(ZMQ::SOCKOPT_LINGER, 500);
        $this->socket->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:" . ZMQ_PORT);
    }
    function publish($topic, $msg){
        $data = ['topic' => "mb.$topic", 'msg' => $msg];
        $this->socket->send(json_encode($data), ZMQ::MODE_DONTWAIT);
    }
}
```

In the pusher file put someting like:

```
public function onSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
    $log = $this->getLogger();
    $topicId = $topic->getId();
    $log->info(sprintf('A client subscribed to %s', $topicId));
    // you could broadcast that user x joined the discussion
}
public function onUnSubscribe(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic) {
    $log = $this->getLogger();
    $topicId = $topic->getId();
    $log->info(sprintf('A client unsubscribed from %s', $topicId));
    // you could broadcast that user x leaved the discussion
}
public function onOpen(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $log = $this->getLogger();
    $log->info(sprintf('Client %d connected', $conn->resourceId));
    $this->clients[$conn->resourceId] = array(); // this will allow you to save state information of the client, you can modify in onSubscribe and onUnsubscribe
    // clients will contain the list of all clients
}
public function onClose(ConnectionInterface $conn) {
    $log = $this->getLogger();
    $log->info(sprintf('Client %d disconnected', $conn->resourceId));
    // you could broadcast that user x leaved the discussion
}
public function onPublish(ConnectionInterface $conn, $topic, $event, array $exclude, array $eligible) {
    $log = $this->getLogger();
    $topicId = $topic->getId();
    $log->info(sprintf('Client %d published to %s : %s', $conn->resourceId, $topicId, json_encode($event)));
    foreach($topic->getIterator() as $peer){
        if(!in_array($peer->WAMP->sessionId, $exclude)){
            $peer->event($topicId, $event);
        }
    }
}
```

The last piece is on the client. If a user opens the page `mysite/allposts`, in javascript you include `autobahn.js`. The websocket will be made available under the variable `ab`. You then do:

When opening the page :

```
var currentSession;
ab.connect(
    Paths.ws,
    function(session) { // onconnect
        currentSession = session
        onWsConnect(session)
    },
    function(code, reason, detail) {// onhangup
        onWsDisconnect(code, reason, detail)
    },{
        maxRetries: 60,
        retryDelay: 2000,
        skipSubprotocolCheck: true
    }
)
currentSession.subscribe('posts', onPostReceived)

function onPostReceived(topic, message){
    //display the new post
}
```

When closing the page:

```
currentSession.unsubscribe(topic)
```

You note that I kept everything very general. This allows me for having several types of messages handled by the same system. What differs are the ZMQ messages and the arguments of `currentSession.subscribe`.

I my implementation, I also keep track of the logged in users that opened the connection, but I stripped this part of the code.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: (untaggable) One important thing I come to know is that 'Ratchet is a server side script that is able to listen to ZMQ messages'. Concept-wise I understood this. But I quite did not understand how it works in a technical way (coding). I think in the controller's method (in the above question) is creating a ZMQ message which is being transmitted as Json encoded message to Ratchet. RIGHT THERE ! I did not understand where and how this encoded message is received by Ratchet and how ratchet would know that method has run. Which part of the code does that?

Comment: Finally i made my application working with Ratchet although I did not use ZMQ this time. My application is small, so opted not to use ZMQ this time. The explanation you gave about how autobahn.js of its coherence with web-socket is very helpful. I will refer this answer again in the future when I have to use ZMQ on my application if my application grows larger.