# How to define a route when using Ratchet web socket?

Tags: javascript, php, sockets, zeromq, ratchet

I am new to this field regarding web socket. I am trying to create a simple real time application built on PHP. I found that Ratchet is one of the best choice for PHP as it eases for native PHP socket programming. I followed the 'Hello world' tutorial found in Ratchet official site [hello world](http://socketo.me/docs/hello-world). This tutorial is basic and it just shows how to make the entire tutorial through web-browser console.

As per the tutorial it has provided a simple shell script that we need to execute so that Ratchet web socket runs as a service alongside Apache server. Below is the Shell script:

```
use Ratchet\Server\IoServer;
use Ratchet\Http\HttpServer;
use Ratchet\WebSocket\WsServer;
use MyApp\Chat;

    require dirname(__DIR__) . '/vendor/autoload.php';

    $server = IoServer::factory(
        new HttpServer(
            new WsServer(
                new Chat()
            )
        ),
        8080
    );

    $server->run();
```

In the above code, it says that web socket is accessible via `port 8080`. I went to browser and browser for `localhost:8080` server is running without any error and browsing localhost:8080 in the browser is displayed without any error. I guess everything is going well.

The next thing is to establish a connection from the client side which can be done by supplying javascript code in the browser console. (Below is the javascript code)

```
var conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:8080');
conn.onopen = function(e) {
    console.log("Connection established!");
};

conn.onmessage = function(e) {
    console.log(e.data);
};
```

When I run the above code, connection is established without any error. Now the problem is I do not know where to put the above JavaScript code so that I do not have to write in console everytime. I guess it should be saved in some javascript files. The above code works in port `localhost:8080`. But how can I mention explicitly that the link `localhost:8080/chat.php` where chat.php would be the desired page that will be shown in the browser and maybe I can put the above JavaScript code in the same file.

I do not know If my question is valid or not, I am just too beginner in this field. I have also asked another question [Binding ZMQ Socket and Ratchet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31366855/how-to-bind-zeromq-socket-with-ratchet-web-socket-library-to-make-real-time-appl/31366990#31366990) regarding the same subject but have not been satisfied yet .

Answer (score 4):

In order to use routes you need to make use of the Symphony Routing functionality built into Ratchet.

Basically your socket initialisation would look like this

```
$app = new Ratchet\App("localhost", 8080, '0.0.0.0', $loop);
$app->route('/chat', new Chat, array('*'));

$app->run();
```

This tutorial goes into more detail and explains some more simple tricks with PHP WebSockets

https://blog.samuelattard.com/the-tutorial-for-php-websockets-that-i-wish-had-existed/

Comment: But how works routes in: IoServer::factory(new HttpServer(new WsServer([...]))); ?

Comment: This has all changed for anybody using the latest version of Ratchet. As Oscar mentions above, this answer is now obsolete. Does anybody know how to do routing with the latest version? The docs don't address it at all.

Comment: It would be nice if the documentation had some examples.  I am at a complete loss how to use this.  Ratchet is quite good at what it is designed for but the documentation needs a lot of work.  Almost no documentation on this and the OriginCheck feature.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the response of MarshallOfSound
I have found some way to use the routing with the new version of Ratchet

```
$app = new Ratchet\App('127.0.0.1',8080);
$app->route('/chat', new Chat(), ['*']);
$app->run();
```

This code work, using the router with the HTTPServer object.